# Pi 3 Maximum Output Resolution

Tags: screen

I know that a lot of people have written extensively on the problems of outputting 4k video from the Raspberry Pi. I have a similar, but related question, can the Raspberry Pi simply output static images to 4k?

I ask because I'm building a reconfigurable digital gameboard and I would like to make the resolution as high as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can

[This forum user](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=79330) got 4k HDMI output working on their pi, and shared a sample config file. Simply use that config file, and display the images as you normally would, they will display at 4k.

Comment: This seems to be only at 15 Hz though, which is pretty tricky.

Comment: Very good point, however the application is for static images, so frame rate shouldn't be an issue